# tcptraceroute stops at second hop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, email, microsoft-outlook, smtp

My roommate and I both have separate routers, but we each share the same ISP.

In an attempt to rule out DNS issues, I used `dig smtp-mail.outlook.com` while connected to my personal network to find the IP address of "smtp-mail.outlook.com":

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;smtp-mail.outlook.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
smtp-mail.outlook.com.  98  IN  CNAME   smtp.live.com.
smtp.live.com.      2456    IN  CNAME   smtp.glbdns2.microsoft.com.
smtp.glbdns2.microsoft.com. 131 IN  A   65.55.163.152
```

Then, while still connected to my personal network, I performed a tcptraceroute:

```
~ ➜ sudo tcptraceroute 65.55.163.152 587
Selected device en0, address 192.168.1.183, port 51220 for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to 65.55.163.152 on TCP port 587 (submission), 30 hops max
 1  192.168.1.1  1.641 ms  0.703 ms  0.657 ms
 2  66.158.233.xxx  1.017 ms  1.031 ms  0.909 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
Destination not reached
```

Afterwards, I connected to my roommate's network and did the same thing. The following response was given:

```
~ ➜ sudo tcptraceroute 65.55.163.152 587        
Selected device en0, address 192.168.1.13, port 51161 for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to 65.55.163.152 on TCP port 587 (submission), 30 hops max
 1  192.168.1.1  2.245 ms  12.245 ms  1.460 ms
 2  66.158.233.xxx  1.861 ms  3.033 ms  1.458 ms
 3  237-0-111-208-in-addr-arpa.omnispring.net (208.111.0.237)  4.751 ms  1.842 ms  1.372 ms
 4  157-10-111-208-in-addr-arpa.omnispring.net (208.111.10.157)  3.618 ms  6.760 ms  4.132 ms
 5  te0-0-1-2.nr11.b006655-1.mco01.atlas.cogentco.com (38.104.89.137)  11.454 ms  5.082 ms  8.654 ms
 6  te0-0-1-1.rcr11.mco01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.24.23.201)  5.886 ms  8.745 ms  5.421 ms
 7  te0-0-1-0.rcr21.tpa01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.24.44.214)  8.267 ms  7.475 ms  7.079 ms
 8  be2745.ccr22.mia01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.1.137)  13.722 ms  21.922 ms  14.404 ms
 9  be2055.ccr21.mia03.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.24.234)  14.018 ms  23.091 ms  15.092 ms
10  38.104.94.122  22.733 ms  16.203 ms  11.482 ms
11  ae14-0.mia-96cbe-1b.ntwk.msn.net (198.206.164.165)  13.262 ms  16.312 ms  15.277 ms
12  be-75-0.ibr02.atb.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.224.230)  36.408 ms  35.275 ms  46.426 ms
13  be-3-0.ibr01.bn1.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.4.49)  37.250 ms  546.708 ms  39.023 ms
14  be-1-0.ibr02.bn1.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.4.63)  41.006 ms  38.616 ms  36.900 ms
15  be-3-0.ibr02.was05.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.4.26)  42.879 ms  35.490 ms  43.147 ms
16  ae71-0.bl2-96c-1b.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.8.173)  41.727 ms  35.650 ms  34.375 ms
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  65.55.163.152 [open]  50.886 ms  53.293 ms  48.313 ms
```

What does this mean?

**EDIT**

Here's what happens when I try port 443.

```
sudo tcptraceroute 65.55.163.152 443
Password:
Selected device en0, address 192.168.1.183, port 52721 for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to 65.55.163.152 on TCP port 443 (https), 30 hops max
 1  192.168.1.1  5.716 ms  2.333 ms  2.286 ms
 2  66.158.233.xxx  5.924 ms  2.056 ms  4.492 ms
 3  237-0-111-208-in-addr-arpa.omnispring.net (208.111.0.237)  2.899 ms  4.417 ms  9.569 ms
 4  157-10-111-208-in-addr-arpa.omnispring.net (208.111.10.157)  7.469 ms  3.429 ms  3.378 ms
 5  te0-0-1-2.nr11.b006655-1.mco01.atlas.cogentco.com (38.104.89.137)  4.240 ms  8.789 ms  5.504 ms
 6  te0-0-1-1.rcr11.mco01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.24.23.201)  7.875 ms  8.628 ms  5.733 ms
 7  te0-0-1-0.rcr21.tpa01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.24.44.214)  11.645 ms  6.852 ms  6.923 ms
 8  be2745.ccr22.mia01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.1.137)  18.506 ms  15.501 ms  17.734 ms
 9  be2055.ccr21.mia03.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.24.234)  18.604 ms  14.386 ms  16.901 ms
10  38.104.94.122  12.786 ms  18.877 ms  12.185 ms
11  ae14-0.mia-96cbe-1b.ntwk.msn.net (198.206.164.165)  15.853 ms  17.492 ms  19.043 ms
12  be-75-0.ibr02.atb.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.224.230)  39.239 ms  36.748 ms  43.531 ms
13  be-3-0.ibr01.bn1.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.4.49)  39.055 ms  37.077 ms  38.916 ms
14  be-1-0.ibr02.bn1.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.4.63)  37.130 ms  37.006 ms  36.756 ms
15  be-3-0.ibr02.was05.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.4.26)  36.872 ms  38.863 ms  41.139 ms
16  ae71-0.bl2-96c-1b.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.8.173)  37.641 ms  36.269 ms  34.535 ms
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
Destination not reached
```

Comment: Can you repeat this? Is the result similar after multiple tries?

Comment: @hyph Just ran tcptraceroute on my personal network two more times; same result.

Comment: How are the networks connected? Is your entire network a node on his?  Or do you each have your own modem from the isp?

Comment: Does normal web browsing work ?   The issue must lie with the configuration or firmware in your router.  Also, what happens if you attempt a different port - eg 443 ?

Comment: @Tyson To be honest, I'm not 100% sure if we each have our own modem. (Not going to lie, I'm still somewhat new to this.) The apartment included internet. What I can say with certainty is that we each have a single ethernet port available in our respective rooms, and that each room's port maps to its own unique public IP. Not sure that answers your question though...

Comment: @davidgo Nope, can't say I've run into any notable issues with general web browsing. I originally noticed this issue while trying to get SMTP notifications working on a media server of mine. I've appended the result of `tcptraceroute 65.55.163.152 443` to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated information, it would seem to me that your router is running some kind of proxy on port 80, thus TTL's of packets never increase above 2 and time out.  By using port 443 you are avoiding this proxy.

Comment: My router has the following firmware installed: https://asuswrt.lostrealm.ca/. I can't seem to find any configuration settings that relate to blocking port 80. Any suggestions for troubleshooting this?